# “Don’t jump on the couch.” Ambiguity

Tags: adverbial-phrases

Can “don’t jump on the couch” mean “don’t jump off the couch,” or does it only mean “don’t jump onto the couch”?

How to recommend someone be on the couch and then jump? I think there’s no word like “onfrom” in English.

According to what I found, I can use “I jumped from on the couch,” but I don’t know it’s idiomatic.

Comment: The word for "onfrom" is actually **off**, as in "Now jump **off** the boat!"

Comment: @stangdon But I want to distinguish among “infrom,” “onfrom,” “overfrom,” “byfrom,” etc.

Comment: /@user0038 All you'll need then, is a dictionary for the language that has all those words.

Comment: @Jack O’Flaherty Haha, nice joke.

Comment: @user0038  You would have to explain what you mean by "overfrom" or "byfrom" or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions are difficult.

“I jumped from on the couch" is understandable, but not idiomatic.

Let's take a look at the things you might want to say to a naughty child.

1. the child is bouncing up and down on the couch. You could say

> don’t jump up and down on the couch - *completely unambiguous*
> don’t jump around on the couch - *clear*
> don’t jump on the couch - *reasonably clear*

The last one is valid because they are on the couch and they are jumping

2. The child is jumping from somewhere else onto the couch. You could say

> don’t jump onto the couch - *completely unambiguous*
> don’t jump on the couch - *reasonably clear*

The last one is valid because **on** can mean **onto**

3. The child is jumping from the couch to somewhere else. You could say:

> don’t jump off on the couch - *completely unambiguous*
> don’t jump on the couch - *just about possible*

The last one is valid because they are on the couch before they jump off it.