# “I run out in the cave.”

Tags: ambiguity

Can “I run out in the cave” mean both “I run out into the cave” and “I run out of the cave”?

For example, “jump on the couch” means “jump onto the couch” and “jump off the couch.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I run out in the cave

If the meaning of **run** is **to move quickly**, the person seems to be entering and exiting the cave at the same time.

Perhaps you mean something like, **While I am in the cave, I run out of it.** No one would ever say that. If you run out of something, it is implied that were in it to begin with.

> I run out into the cave

This might make sense if we imagine that the door of a house is a meter away from the entrance to a cave. Or perhaps a house has been constructed inside a cave. Someone speaking in a hurry might use it to mean **I run out OF THE HOUSE into the cave.** But seriously, these scenarios stretch the imagination.

If you are referring to [this couch question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/291583/don-t-jump-on-the-couch-ambiguity), none of the contributors agreed that **jump on the couch** can also mean **jump off the couch.** It is possible to imagine a situation where someone might mean that, but the situation would be so unusual that it is not worth the effort to think about it.

The only sentence that makes sense is this:

> I run out of the cave

If the intended meaning is **I leave the cave, and I am moving quickly by foot**, then that is the normal way to say it.